# How to compare hex-encoded strings returned by SHA-256 function in MS SQL and Snowflake?

Tags: sql-server, hash, cryptography, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm looking for a hash function in Snowflake and SQL Server that returns the same SHA-256 string value. So I decided to compare hex-encoded strings returned by [sha2](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/sha2.html) (SHA-256) function from Snowflake and HASHBYTES (SHA2_256) from SQL Server.
Here are the queries that I've made:

**Snowflake:**

```
SELECT sha2(TO_VARCHAR(ABS(12.5)), 256)
Returns: b902cc4550838229a710bfec4c38cbc7eb11082367a409df9135e7f007a96bda
```

**SQL Server:**

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(64), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CAST(12.5 AS varbinary(64))), 2) as tmp
Returns: 48DCB7B99301A1AA2D8A74637173AD8A3282844983F39ED7AB079A2ADF08FEEA
```

They appear to return different hash strings. Do these functions indeed have a different underlying implementation or something is wrong with the queries?

I suspect that there might be a mistake in my query to SQL Server.

Comment: Does  `CAST(12.5 AS varbinary(64))` output the same bytes as `TO_VARCHAR(ABS(12.5))`?

Comment: Sqlserver: `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(64), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CAST(12.5 AS varchar(64))), 2) as tmp`

Answer (score 2):

I get the same results in SQL Server and Snowflake with this example:

SQL Server:

```
SELECT UPPER(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HashBytes('SHA2_256', 'Hello World'), 1, 0))
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256','Hello World'), 2);

SELECT UPPER(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HashBytes('SHA2_256', '12.5'), 1, 0))
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256','12.5'), 2);
```

Snowflake:

```
SELECT sha2(TO_VARCHAR('Hello World'), 256);

SELECT sha2(TO_VARCHAR('12.5'), 256);
```

**RESULTS FOR BOTH:**

```
Hello World: A591A6D40BF420404A011733CFB7B190D62C65BF0BCDA32B57B277D9AD9F146E 
12.5: B902CC4550838229A710BFEC4C38CBC7EB11082367A409DF9135E7F007A96BDA
```